# strange IPython behavior: "pass", "return", or "raise" in variable name terminates function/class definition

Tags: python, definition, ipython, reserved-words, function-declaration

I have been working through the [SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html%5d) in an IPython shell and got to the point where I had to put `password = Column(String)` in a class definition. Oddly, the class definition terminated as soon as I entered it.

After playing around a bit, I've found that any line starting with `pass`, `return`, or `raise` in a class or function definition, such as

```
def f(x):
    returnfoo = None
```

terminates the definition in IPython. This doesn't happen in the default python interpreter, so it's not a python issue. I would assume it's a bug in IPython, but wanted to make sure it's not just my system; can anyone verify this behavior?

EDIT: I was using IPython 0.11.dev for Python 2.6 preinstalled on Mac OS X Snow Leopard. On 0.10.2 it doesn't actually terminate the function/class definition-- neither does

```
def f(x):
    return
```

but it does mistakenly reset the indentation so that if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again the class definition will end.

Comment: That would be a bug. If you grab the latest 0.11.dev from github, it should be working. It was fixed last month: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/346

Answer (score 1):

It does not work that way on my system.

```
In [1]: def f(x):
   ...:     returnfoo = None
   ...:     return returnfoo
   ...:
```

My version:

```
$ ipython -V
0.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have that issue:

```
>>> def f(x):
    returnfoo = None
    return x
...: 

>>> f(1)
<<< 1
```